# Excel: Fill row cells

Tags: excel

I have a table in Excel which is grouped vertically but has empty rows indicating that the fields in that row correspond to that group above.

Example:

```
Column A        Column B    Column C    Colunm D
Classroom A     Course A    Teacher A   Student 1
                                        Student 2
                            Teacher B   Student 3
                Course B    Teacher A   Student  1
```

I just need the the empty fields below to be copied from above.

Result:

```
Column A        Column B    Column C    Colunm D
Classroom A     Course A    Teacher A   Student 1
Classroom A     Course A    Teacher A   Student 2
Classroom A     Course A    Teacher B   Student 3
Classroom A     Course B    Teacher A   Student 1
```

Comment: Are you looking for  VBA solution?  If so, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your posted data, try this simple macro:

```
Sub GetAFillUp()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A2:D4")
    For Each r In rng
        If r.Value = "" Then
            r.Value = r.Offset(-1, 0).Value
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: I think the range rows count should dynamic.

Comment: @Amejel ............then **rng** can easily be expanded.....what is important is that **rng** starts *1 row* **below** the actual data table values......

Comment: Agreed. Hey how do you get the last row filled with data in a column in one line?

Comment: @Amejel  If you assume that column **D** is filled **at the bottom** then **nLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row**  If the bottom row is REALLY jagged, then I would loop over columns to find that last row.

Comment: Thanks man! Appreciate it. I's better the one I use often Replace(Range("D").End(XlDown).Address,"$D$","").

Comment: If there are merged cells in the way, wouldn't the code run into a stop?

Comment: How about copying the content, unmerging the cells, running the code through, merging back them again and pasting the content back in? That sounds like a lot of typing and head-scratching.

Comment: I will .... when I have to... lol I have lots of Excel and SW macros to bend over at work. Enough for another month.

Answer (score 0):

Create a blank template containing only the column headers.

In the first cell of the row below the column headers, let's say A2, enter the formula `=A1`. This will make A2 have the same value as the cell above it, unless it's overridden. Select this cell (A2), copy, and paste to all of the columns that you want to have this repeating feature, for more than enough rows. (That is, if you want the feature to work in the first three columns, and if you anticipate never needing more than 100 rows, paste to the range A2 - C101.)

Now, make a copy of the blank template, and enter your data into the appropriate cells. Each value will be copied downward until the next manually-entered value. If you need to do this again, start over with a new copy of your blank template.

If you enter a value but then want to delete it, copy one of the cells that's still automatically copied from above and paste it into the cell you want to delete. That will revert it back to being automatically filled in from above.